# Caddy: Use client cert in reverse_proxy for authentication

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I am setting up a local dev environment in which I am proxying certain requests to a back-end server.

When calling the back-end server directly, I get the below browser prompt for a local certificate for authentication.

How can I do the same thing in a `reverse_proxy` directive in my Caddyfile (passing the certificate to the back-end)? I have tried tracing the calls in Developer Tools but I don't see how the certificate is included in the request (headers).

[image: Browser pop-up for certificate prompt]

I thought I could maybe include a `tls` directive inside the `route` where I define the proxying to take place, but Caddy complains, saying

> tls directive returned something other than an HTTP route or
> subroute

```
    route /abc/def/* {
            tls internal {
                    client_auth {
                            trusted_leaf_cert_file "C:\path\to\local.cer"
                    }
            }                               
            uri replace /abc/def /ghi/jkl
            reverse_proxy https://back-end.service {
                    header_up Authorization "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will answer your question, though Caddy offers the option to specify a certificate to send to the backend.

Within the reverse proxy block in the CaddyFile you can add the following:

```
transport http {
     tls_client_auth <automate_name> | <cert_file> <key_file>
}
```

For a full explanation check their docs: https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/reverse_proxy#the-http-transport